# How to get object ID using C API in Python?

Tags: python, cpython, python-c-api

I wonder - is there a canonical way of getting object's ID using CPython's C API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object id is just the pointer value:

```
PyObject *some_py_object = ...;
intptr_t id = (intptr_t)some_py_object;
```

Or if you [want it as a Python object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/89a2209ae6fc5f39868621799730e16f931eb497/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1170):

```
PyLong_FromVoidPtr(some_py_object)
```

---

This is a CPython specific implementation detail. If you're concerned about compatibility with other versions of Python (e.g. PyPy through their C API compatibility layer) you should probably import [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), get the attribute `id` and call it, using the normal C-API mechanisms for doing that.

Comment: intptr_t id = (intptr_t) some_py_object;  // cast is needed